# Which one is correct – "dieser Laptop" or "diesen Laptop"?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative, nominative

In the sentence

> Dieser Laptop gehört mir nicht.

Should it be *diesen* or *dieser*? I am confused because I would think you would have to use *diesen* because of *gehört*, but apparently that's wrong.

I am thinking it is because "Gehört mir nicht" is dative and not accusative.

Comment: What is the subject of the sentence?

Comment: I added the tag nominative, as this is the correct answer. Note, that dative would be "diesem" with an M, i.e. "diesem Laptop". Also, the verb does not matter at all as we're talking about the subject. The subject is always in nominative case. "Gehört mir nicht" is not dative, the only part which is dative is the object "mir".

Answer (score 5):

In this case the demonstrative pronoun has to be in nominative and thus be *dieser*.
Though, in German the noun *Laptop* can either be masculine or neutral, so both *dieser* and *dieses* would be correct.

Comment: I'm a german native speaker and have never hear `das Laptop`.

Comment: @raznagul I've heard it a couple of times, but 'der Laptop' is definitely predominantly. According to the Duden both is correct.

Comment: One way to determine the correct form if you're having difficulty would be to consider which pronoun you would use to replace laptop. For example, in English you would say: "It belongs to me." In German: "Er/es gehört mir." Clearly, the pronoun is 1st person singular masculine. Thus, the corresponding demonstrative should fit that pattern too. Apparently in this situation, "der Laptop" is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the nominative case (1st case), because Laptop is the subject of the sentence and *dies/er* is a demonstrative adjective.

Correct is:

> *Dieser* Laptop gehört mir.

*diesen* would be accusative (4th case).

---

Declication table of dieser, diese, dies:

```
           nominative genitive dative  accusative
           ---------- -------- ------  ----------
masculine  dieser     dieses   diesem  diesen
feminine   diese      dieser   dieser  diese
neuter     dieses     dieses   diesem  dieses
plural     diese      dieser   diesen  diese
```